# How I can determine if there is another element after the current one or not in java using list Structures in java

Tags: java, linked-list, structure, element, implementation

I'm trying to write an function named boolean hasNext() which checks if there is another element after the current one or not
 I have an class named TourElement, it contains a lot of points.
Here is my code
// class waypoint:

```
public class Waypoint {
    int x  ;
    int y  ;
    public int getX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }
    public void setXY(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
```

//class tourElement

```
 public class TourElement {
     private Waypoint points;
     private TourElement next;

      public void setWaypoint( Waypoint points){
       this.points = points; 
     }
      public void setTourElement(TourElement next) {
          this.next = next;
      }
     Waypoint getWaypoint() {
         return this.points;
     }

     TourElement getNext(){
         return this.next;
     }

    boolean hasNext(Waypoint first){
    // What am I doing wrong here?
        TourElement current = getNext();
        while( current.next != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    // my test case
         public void testHasNext()
        {
           TourElement elem = createElementList(new int[][] {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}});

            assertEquals(true,elem.hasNext(createWaypoint(1, 1)));
        }
```

//create element list:

```
private TourElement createElementList(int[][] waypoints){
        assert waypoints.length > 0;
        TourElement elem = new TourElement();
        int lastIndex = waypoints.length-1;
        Waypoint wp = createWaypoint(waypoints[lastIndex][0], waypoints[lastIndex][1]);
        elem.setWaypoint(wp);
        for (int i = lastIndex-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            wp = createWaypoint(waypoints[i][0], waypoints[i][1]);
            elem = elem.addStart(wp);
        }
        return elem;
    }
```

// create waypoint:

```
private Waypoint createWaypoint(int x, int y) {
        Waypoint wp = new Waypoint();
        wp.setXY(x, y);
        return wp;
    }
```

I expect that with my hasNext Function, if I pass an point like {1,1}, it will return true because there is one more point after this point. but when I pass{2,2}. it will return false

Comment: You put a sort of List insie an element, please the code of the method you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method can be improved. Take a look

```
boolean hasNext(){
    if (this.next != null) return true;
    return false;
}
```

You don't need to loop to the end of the LinkledList, you should only care about what is next.

Comment: How I can write exacly the test case with hasNext() function like that?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
assertEquals(true,elem.hasNext(createWaypoint(1, 1)));
```

Will always fail the assertion, because you're creating a *new* waypoint, and then attempting to find it in the list of existing waypoints.  But this new waypoint *isn't in the list*.

The only waypoints in the list are the ones that you added, and this is a  brand new waypoint that just happens to have the same x and y values as one of the waypoints in your list.

You don't include the code for the `TourElement.addStart` method, so I can't tell if there's any issue there.  And others have pointed out that you don't need a loop inside `hasNext`. But the main issue here is that you need to do something other than use the `WayPoint` passed into the `hasNext` method.  This will likely involve traversing the waypoint graph trying to find an existing `WayPoint` with the same x and y values as the one passed into the method, and then checking to see if *that* has a `next`.